# Write to Azure Storage Blob (PowerShell)

Tags: azure, powershell, azure-functions, azure-blob-storage

I'm trying to write to an Azure Storage blob using a PowerShell Azure Function. I can't find any documentation online for accomplishing this for PowerShell only C#. This is what I have

```
using namespace System.Net

# Input bindings are passed in via param block.
param($Request, $TriggerMetadata)

# Interact with query parameters or the body of the request.
$var1 = $Request.Query.var1
if (-not $var1) {
    $var1 = $Request.Body.var1
}

$body = "This HTTP triggered function executed successfully. Pass a name in the query string or in the request body for a personalized response."

if ($var1) {
    $body = "Variable 1: $var1"
}

outputBlob.WriteLine("test")


# Associate values to output bindings by calling 'Push-OutputBinding'.
Push-OutputBinding -Name Response -Value ([HttpResponseContext]@{
    StatusCode = [HttpStatusCode]::OK
    Body = $Body
})
```

When I execute function I get

`ERROR: outputBlob.WriteLine : The term 'outputBlob.WriteLine' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program.`

Azure Blob Stroage has been added as Output Integration.

```
Binding Type: Azure Blob Storage
Blob parameter name: outputBlob
Path: {function}/{rand-guid}
Storage Account Connection: myStorageAccount
```

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: This: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/common/storage-rest-api-auth and this https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/storageservices/put-blob should get you in the right direction.

Comment: It might be easier for you to move over to C# in the Function instead of PowerShell and follow this guide: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-bindings-storage-blob-output?tabs=csharp

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out. I need Push-OutputBinding.

This worked for me

Push-OutputBinding -Name outputBlob -Value 'test'